# JMeter: How may I sum random 2 float numbers

Tags: http, request, jmeter, decimal

How do I allow jmeter to generate 2 seperate decimal values and use it in 2 parameters in http requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a random float value using either any of [JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) or [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy), the relevant code would be something like:

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextFloat(0.0f, 100f)
```

*in case of _groovy() function you need to escape the comma like:*

```
${__groovy(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextFloat(0.0f\, 100f),)}
```

it will return a random float number in range from 0 to 100 (adjust as needed)

Demo:

[image: JMeter Groovy Sum Random Floats]

More information: [Mathematical Functions and Converting Data Types in Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mathematical-functions-and-converting-data-types-in-groovy)