# JMeter: How to generate 2 random float numbers in particular range and use it further

Tags: multithreading, variables, jmeter

Scenario is:
Generate 1 random float number in between 0.01 to 500 and pass it as var_1

Generate 1 more float number in range of 0.01 to 0.17 and save it as var_2

Now, whatever is the number picked up by JMeter as var_1, add var_2 to it i.e: var_1+var_2 and pass it as var_3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recall answering something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52500217/jmeter-how-may-i-sum-random-2-float-numbers/52503624#52503624), however probably I missed the step of storing the values into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

In JMeter's Groovy you have `vars` shorthand which stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance so you can use it to write generated values and their sum into the required variables like:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils

def float1 = RandomUtils.nextFloat(0.01f, 500f)
def float2 = RandomUtils.nextFloat(0.01f, 0.17f)
def sum = float1 + float2

vars.put('var_1', float1 as String)
vars.put('var_2', float2 as String)
vars.put('var_3', sum as String)
```

You can verify generated variables along with their values using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree Listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) combination:

[image: JMeter Variables Checking with Debug Sampler]

Comment: I see floa number passing as "146.14926" or "146.3159078359604" any option we can have values like 0.01 or 124.00 or 6.05 basically number with 2 decimals, not more

Comment: Something like `new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(float1)`

Comment: doesnt work. tried ###.### 
###.# 
###,###.## 
000.### 
##0.### none working