# JMeter: How to pass random number that contains decimal?

Tags: random, jmeter, numbers, decimal

We have to pass values random between 8, 8.5, 9, 9.5, 10, 10.5 like wise till 99. How may I achieve this?

Comment: Please refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52510549/jmeter-how-to-generate-2-random-float-numbers-in-particular-range-and-use-it-fu

Comment: Thats not the same, in that pattern is not same like the one I need it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I heard [Groovy is the new black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) so you can use [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) for implementing your requirement like:

```
${__groovy(new java.text.DecimalFormat('0.#').format(Math.ceil(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextFloat(8.1f\, 99f) * 2) / 2),)}
```

[image]

References:

- [RandomUtils.nextFloat()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomUtils.html#nextFloat-float-float-)
- [Math.ceil()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil(double))
- [Customizing Formats](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html)